# How to create Bubble chart in C3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I am trying to create a Bubble chart using C3js chart. I've selected chart type as 'scatter'. Is there any way can join the bubbles in below format [image]

Answer (score 2):

There is an undocumented **C3.js extension** for bubble chart:

https://github.com/c3js/c3/blob/master/extensions/chart-bubble/

Which introduce the `bubble` type.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/do2kLLjp/

Probably other chart library are preferably for this chart type:

- chart.js: http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scriptable/bubble.html
- highcarts: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble

Comment: The link to last fiddle is duplicate. Could you provide the right one please?